# Php code does not work inside javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have this php code:

```
<?php

    $myVar=$_GET['MyVar'];
?>
```

then, in my javascript, I wrote:

```
var p="<?php echo $myVar;?>";

window.open("./myurl.php?MyVar="+p,"_self");
```

But it th php code is ignored and read just like if it was a simple String, so my url is:

```
./myurl.php?MyVar=<?php%20echo%20$myVar;?>
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: I think your server isn't parsing the php code

Comment: whats your file extension ... is it php or html or something else?

Comment: Really executing in server? or Opened just the html file in browser?

Comment: Use ajax! It is especially simple using jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your script file must be .js.php to work or you must wrote this script in .php file
if you want use .js.php file add `header("Content-type: text/javascript")`
good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Just have to ask. The value that you get from `$myVar` doesn't contain any "s right?
If your variable uses any sort of special characters you should also use `json_encode()` as follows:

```
var p = <?php echo json_encode($myVar); ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another trick for you
 
If you're using a simple PHP inserted with HTML (not MVC or templates), but your .js files are separate from .php files, you could also use the following trick:

1- In PHP:

`$myVar = $_GET['MyVar'];`

`echo "<script>var p = \"{$myVar}\";</script>";`

Thus, you will create (print) a chunk of Javascript, that will initialize the variable.

2- In JavaScript

`window.open("./myurl.php?MyVar="+p,"_self");`

So you just use it, it's already there.